# Location of old Pocket Chrome Webapp (Packaged App) to copy to new laptop

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, pocket

The [Chrome web app for Pocket](https://www.omgchrome.com/pocket-goes-packaged-app-runs-offline/) (Packaged App) used to be able to store articles offline [is no longer available](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pocket/mjcnijlhddpbdemagnpefmlkjdagkogk). The [help page](https://help.getpocket.com/article/1136-using-pocket-offline) says only MacOS offline desktop app exists.

I have a laptop with a relatively old install of (Arch) Linux, with Chromium, with this web app installed. It still works flawlessly.

I would like to make a backup of this web app (to copy to laptops with newer installs, that don't have this app and cannot download it), but cannot find the location of it.

Does somebody know where I can find the app?

The command to launch the packaged app is:

```
/usr/bin/chromium --profile-directory=Default --app-id=mjcnijlhddpbdemagnpefmlkjdagkogk
```

Alternatively is there a download location of the Chrome web app pocket? (not the "save to pocket" extension, but the old web app that allowed offline reading).

[image: Chrome Pocket Offline Package / Web app]
[image: ubuntu version]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out:

1. Download or clone this repo: https://github.com/bquast/Pocket-Chrome-App/
2. Open chrome / chromium settings
3. Navigate to security
4. Change from "standard" to "off"
5. Open chrome://extensions
6. Choose "Unpackaged install"
7. Select the folder containing this repo
8. Install
9. Switch security back to "standard"